# Calculating T2 statistics in R

Tags: r, matrix, mean, covariance, variance

I have a matrix x:

```
> x
      x1 x2
 [1,]  6  9
 [2,] 10  6
 [3,]  8  3
```

I am trying to T^2 statistics:

```
> library(DescTools)
> HotellingsT2Test(x)

Hotelling's one sample T2-test for mu' = [9, 5]

data:  x
T.2 = 28, df1 = 2, df2 = 1, p-value = 0.1325 
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to c(0,0)
```

The statistics seems to be off (the correct answer is 7/9). What am I doing wrong?

Other variables:

```
 > mu
[1] 9 5 
> means
x1 x2 
8  6 
> S # variance-covariance matrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   -3
[2,]   -3    9
> S_inv # inverse matrix
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.1111111
[2,] 0.1111111 0.1481481
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you are not providing the `mu` parameter to the function. But then

```
HotellingsT2Test(x, mu = mu)
# 
#   Hotelling's one sample T2-test
# 
# data:  x
# T.2 = 0.19444, df1 = 2, df2 = 1, p-value = 0.8485
# alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to c(9,5)
```

still isn't what you expect, and that is because by default the decision is based on the F-distribution, in which case the statistic is multiplied by another factor (which is (n - p)/(p * (n - 1)), with n = 3 and p = 2 in your case). Using chi-squared approximation we get, as needed,

```
HotellingsT2Test(x, mu = mu, test = "chi")
#
#   Hotelling's one sample T2-test
# 
# data:  x
# T.2 = 0.77778, df = 2, p-value = 0.6778
# alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to c(9,5)
```